# CE Cache and Detect Mobile

Tags: ce-cache, mobile

I am trying to use CE cache with detect mobile so I can separate the desktop version of my site from the mobile version. I tried appending {exp:detect_mobile:type} to the CE cache id but the tag does not get processed.

Has anyone been able to get the two to play nice with each other or have any idea on how to I could solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I seemed to solve this by adding parse="inward" to the ce_cache:it tag. so my tag ended up looking like this

```
{exp:ce_cache:it id="home_{exp:detect_mobile:type}" seconds="21600" parse="inward"}
```

Hope this helps someone :)

T.